# Pine Script code for multiple buy/sell options

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a pine script indicator with 2 different Buy/Sell alert conditions.

One is the Rsi crosses the 50 level and the +di crosses the -di,
the second condition is when the Rsi crosses 50 level and Adx is greater than 25.

I  want to choose between the two options and if I choose condition  one it should give me a Buy/Sell alert if that condition is met, and the same applies if the 2nd condition are met.

I tried "select" option but failed to get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the user to choose the alert to activate :

```
AlertRsiDi = input.bool(true,"Alert when Rsi crosses the 50 level and the +di crosses the -di ?")
AlertRsiAdx = input.bool(true, "Alert when the Rsi crosses 50 level and Adx is greater than 25 ?")
```

Then if your names of condition are Condition1 and Condition2, to create the alert :

```
if AlertRsiDi and Condition1
    alert("Alerte Rsi Di", alert.freq_all)
if AlertRsiAdx and Condition2
    alert("Alerte Rsi ADX", alert.freq_all)
```

Comment: Thank you vor the quick response, I added it to my scripts but get the following error message "4:34:54 AM Error at 43:19 Undeclared identifier 'Condition1'
4:34:54 AM Error at 45:20 Undeclared identifier 'Condition2'

Comment: @CTrader you said in your question you ha 2 conditions  :just replace condition1 with your first condition and condition2 with your second condition. Without your code, hard to help you more